# YARN REST API returns startedTime and other fields as 0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

When making calls to the YARN REST Api via `curl`, to get the jobs on the cluster, using:

```
curl --negotiate -u : http:<rm url>:<port>/ws/v1/cluster/apps?states=finished,failed,killed
```

In the resulting JSON, I get all the values but `startedTime`, `finishedTime` and `elapsedTime` have value 0.

N.B: On the YARN UI, these values are present, and also when using the cmd `yarn application -status`.

I checked on the API documentation, and I couldn't find a parameter to force the fields returned, is it because of some parameter that I can't get these values?

Comment: Did you mean to go to the Node Manager URL instead of the Resource Manager?

Comment: @tk421 Yes, I did edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'd answer my question in case someone has the same issue.*

After more research, I found that the access to some metrics via the YARN REST API in a Kerberized cluster is restricted via ACLs, only the user who lunched the job and the admin users are able to access these metrics.

To bypass this, we ought to:

```
yarn.admin.acl=false
```

or

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_jobs=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_queue=*
```

Source: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/91199/yarn-web-interface-reporting-0-for-many-metrics-fo.html